# Catalog for Mikhail Glinka's work?

Tags: composers

Is there any existing effort to categorize Glinka's compositions?

Like András Szőllősy (Sz.) and László Somfai (BB.) for Béla Bartók's works, I have noticed quite many sites providing catalog number with "G." prefix for Glinka's works (example: [AllMusic](https://www.allmusic.com/artist/mikhail-glinka-mn0001189348/compositions) [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001FA2WA0) ), but they only contain selected list from albums. So far I failed to come up with a complete list from search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the source myself. It's from М. Глинка. Полное собрание сочинений (M. Glinka: Complete Collection of Works), which is enlisted in Glinka's entry in Grove Dictionary. Quite a selection of the works is listed there as well. Sadly quite a hurdle for those not understanding any Cyrillic.